# PHP NetSSH2 command dropped after few minutes

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssh, ffmpeg, phpseclib

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server,
I want to run a ffmpeg command via remote SSH with PHP.
After around 5 minutes process dropped,
but it wasn't returned any error.
I've tested it directly from ssh and there wasn't any problem.
Also I've increased SSH Connection timeout but my problem is still.

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('IP_ADDRESS');
$ssh->login('root', 'PASSWORD') or die("Login failed");
$command = "sudo ffmpeg -y -i $path/$film -vf subtitles=$path/$subtitle -vcodec h264 -crf 25 $path/$subtitled";
$ssh->exec($command);
```

Comment: Could you provide some more information, e.g. the relevant source code parts. Its's also important how you call the PHP script itself, because there is a maximum execution time in some cases.

Comment: yeah you're right. I've added it.

Comment: How do you call your PHP script? - though a webserver (Apache, Nginx, etc.) or by commandline? Depending on your setup there could be multiple layers with different timeout configurations. You could test if one of theese timeouts is the problem by counting the time of an infinite loop => if the script interupts after the same amount of time you know that the problem is within your PHP setup and not related to the ssh connection. If its not the case it may depend on an SSH timeout of the target system, see http://queirozf.com/entries/disabling-ssh-timeout-when-connecting-to-from-ubuntu

Comment: thanks for help, yeah I know, I increase max_execution_time and the other limits. but still after few minutes the process automatically removed from system. I'm using Nginx.

Comment: Have you restarted/reloaded the server / fcgi / etc. after changing the settings? On which system the process is terminated on Nginx host, or on ffmpeg host or both? Your should try the Server/PHP timeouts with another "clean" script which waits for some minutes to ensure that ssh is the problem.

Comment: "I've increased SSH Connection timeout but my problem is still" How did you do that? I would do so by doing `$ssh->setTimeout(0);`.